# How to implement Dashboard in django admin?

Tags: python, django, admin, dashboard

How to implement Dashboard in django admin?

If I have following Model in django. Is there a way, instead of regular Models list,I can have a search box in admin page to search for student using his name and display his particular details...

```
class MStudent(models.Model):
    enroll_no = models.IntegerField()
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to="static",blank = True)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.FName+" "+ self.MName+" "+ self.LName
class MStud_Address_ph_no_email(models.Model):
    enroll_no = models.ForeignKey(MStudent)
    Address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Personal_mobile= models.IntegerField()
    Fathers_mobile = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
         return str(self.enroll_no)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Django admin documentation:

> If you wish to change the index, login or logout templates, you are better off creating your own AdminSite instance (see below), and changing the AdminSite.index_template , AdminSite.login_template or AdminSite.logout_template properties.

So you should create your own [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#adminsite-objects) and set its `index_template` attribute to a template of yours that implements the Dashboard you want.

To provide a search and a search results view, see [adding views to admin sites](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites).

Comment: writing def get_urls(self): and def my_view(self, request): doesn't work.....my_view doesn't got executed....get_urls() got executed only once Why it is so??

Comment: my_view will be accessed at /admin/myapp/mymodel/my_view/ (assuming the admin URLs are included at /admin/.)  ............. Now I got it

Comment: Only problem is  name 'TemplateResponse' is not defined

Comment: @IqbalHawre You will access it at `/admin/myapp/mymodel/my_view/` if you override a `ModelAdmin.get_urls`, if you override `AdminSite.get_urls`, you will access it at `/admin/my_view/`, it's up to what satisfies your needs best.

Comment: @IqbalHawre you need to import it using `from django.template.response import TemplateResponse`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read the django docs about [admin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/)

And in your case if you want to customize the admin look and feel or adding extra fucntionality, you need override the required admin templates like `admin/index.html` by creating an admin folder in your template directory

Answer (score 0):

Q.Is there a way, instead of regular Models list, I can have a search box in admin page to search for student using his name and display his particular details?

1) Yes Instead of displaying regular Models list I can directly redirect to model Mstudent.using following code

```
urls.py
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
url(r'^admin/$',lambda x:HttpResponseRedirect('/admin/yourapp/yourmodel'))
```

2) To search for student using his name and display his particular details:

```
Make  MStud_Address_ph_no_email as inline to MStudent in admin.py.
```

So all in all whenever a user logged in to django admin, He will directly see list of all students and by selecting a particular student he can see all his details.

:)